# javascript google maps v3 app help - order of instructions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Basically I'm making a nice and simple mobile web app for a couple of my friends. It uses some online databases to store position data of shops. I've got the databases working like a charm. No problems there. In fact everything is working except it's all happening in the wrong order I think. The data from the database should be stored in an array and then the objects in that array are displayed on screen. However, using some console logs I've found that the data is being displayed, then being retrieved from the database, then the arrays are filled. But no matter what I do, I can't get it to work! Here is my code:

```
var latOfSpots;
    var lngOfSpots;
    var nameOfSpots;
    var spotArray;
    var spotLatLng;
    var spotCollection;
    var markers;
    var Spot;
    var spot;

    function init() {

//-------------------------- INITIATE SPOT VARIABLES ---------------------------//  
        map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
        latOfSpots= new Array(51.14400,51.02295);
        lngOfSpots= new Array(0.25721,0.26450);
        nameOfSpots= new Array('Tescos', 'Sainsburys');
        spotLatLng= new Array();
        markers= new Array();
        Spot = Parse.Object.extend("Spot");
        spot = new Spot();

//----------------- GET DATA FROM THE PARSE.COM DATABASE ---------------------//


//---------------------- DISPLAY ARRAY DATA ON MAP ---------------------------//        

        GetData();
        DisplayData();

//----------------------- SET MAP SETTINGS -----------------------------------//
        map.setCenter(spotLatLng[0],8);

        //map.addControl(new google.maps.LargeMapControl());

        map.addControl(new google.maps.MapTypeControl());



    }; //END OF INIT FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------//

    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

//------------------- PRIMARY FUNCTION TO GET DATA FROM DATABASE ---------------//
    function GetData()
    {
                var query = new Parse.Query(Spot);
                spotCollection = query.collection();
                spotCollection.fetch({
                  success: function(spotCollection) {
                    // spotCollection.toJSON() 
                    // will now be an array of objects based on the query
                    FillArrays();
                    console.log('data retreived' + spotCollection);
                  }
        });
    }

//----------------- FUNCTION TO LOAD DATABASE INTO ARRAYS -------------------//
    function FillArrays()
    {
            spotArray = spotCollection.toJSON();
                for (var j = 0; j<spotArray.length; j++)
                {
                    latOfSpots.push(spotArray[j].Latitude);
                    lngOfSpots.push(spotArray[j].Longitude);
                    nameOfSpots.push(spotArray[j].Name);
                }
    }

//------------------------ FUNCTION TO DISPLAY ALL ARRAY DATA ONSCREEN -----------------//
    function DisplayData()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i<latOfSpots.length; i++)
        {
            spotLatLng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(latOfSpots[i], lngOfSpots[i]);

                    for(var x = 0; x<latOfSpots.length; x++)
                    {
                        markers[x] = new google.maps.Marker(
                        spotLatLng[i], {
                        "draggable":false,
                        "title":nameOfSpots[i],
                        });
                        map.addOverlay(markers[x]);
                    }
        }

    console.log('data displayed');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database query is asynchronous.  You need to use the data in the Get_Data callback function (after it has come back from the server).  Currently you are attempting to use it before the server sends it back.

```
//------------------- PRIMARY FUNCTION TO GET DATA FROM DATABASE ---------------//
    function GetData()
    {
                var query = new Parse.Query(Spot);
                spotCollection = query.collection();
                spotCollection.fetch({
                  success: function(spotCollection) {
                    // spotCollection.toJSON() 
                    // will now be an array of objects based on the query
                    FillArrays();
                    console.log('data retreived' + spotCollection);
                    DisplayData();
                  }
        });
    }
```